# Global.asax stopped executing after installing aspnet_regbrowsers.exe utility

Tags: iis-6, global-asax

After running "aspnet_regbrowsers.exe -i" utility my Global.asax file stoped working when site is deployed on IIS 6 (on dev environment everything is fine). Application_Start and Aplication_End events are not firing. Here is a question with the same issue: [Global.asax Events not firing in IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503057/global-asax-events-not-firing-in-iis-6)
I used aspnet_regbrowsers utility to enable ASP.NET 2.0 to recognize modern browsers, such as Chrome.
Is it possible to have both: Global.asax executing and aspnet_regborwsers installed? How?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by moving from machine-level browser definitions to application-level  browser definition, located in App_Browsers folder. I had to modify some of *.browser files from .net 4.0 (http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41420) so they compile after placing in App_Browsers folder.

Comment: you can check your answer as "the answer"